# How to use Onclick in a MVC table and still get jquery to process the click event too

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with an OnClick that works great.

```
<tr onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", new { id = item.CaseNumber, dp = item.DocumentPath, dt = item.DocumentType, sc = Model.SearchCriteria, rds = Model.ReturnDataSel })'">
```

But I want to show a spinner while it gets the data from the Url.Action.
so I have jquery:

```
$("#res_table").click(function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("spin_id");
x.style.display = "block";
```

How do I get both to function at the same time?
I see I can use a .ajax function to do a get call, but I dont know how to reference the data in the html i.e.(id,dp,dt,sc,rds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not merge them into one event?

```
<tr data-url="@(Url.Action("Index", new { id = item.CaseNumber, dp = item.DocumentPath, dt = item.DocumentType, sc = Model.SearchCriteria, rds = Model.ReturnDataSel }))">
```

Then:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
              
    //Gets the URL from the data attribute 
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    
    //Gets the spinner element
    var x = document.getElementById("spin_id");
    
    //Shows spinner element
    x.style.display = "block";
    
    //Redirects to URL
    window.location.href = url ;

});
```